# element position changing when user scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fixed

I'm using this code for changing my header position when user scroll down. That's mean that when user scroll down my header should be fixed.

CSS:

```
.backForward_links {
  border: 1px solid #2B2B2B;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var elementOffset = $(".backForward_links").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos > elementOffset) {
        $(".backForward_links").css({
            'top': '48px',
            'position': 'fixed'
        });
    } else {
        $(".backForward_links").css({
            'top': '0px',
            'position': 'relative'
        });
    }
});
```

What i need now is my header should be fixed just when user scroll up not down.

Comment: What exactly should happen when the user scrolls up and what should happen when the user scrolls down?

Comment: when scrolling down header should not be visible, just after scrolling up